# how to view mac localhost in pc (even php sites)

Tags: localhost, web, mamp

I just found that I can share websites from my mac with other computers in my house, I love this as it could make browser testing a lot easier.

However I just tested this and found that the php files do not work.

At the moment I also have mamp (as I did not know about this web sharing feature)

I hope you can help me somehow as it be a time saving feature

Thanks

Comment: Wow, please try to use _some_ correct terminology at least. I believe you're trying to ask about "internet connection sharing". If thats true, please update your question. Also, what does this have to do with sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those that may want to know how to access you mamp files from different computers within you LAN you simply need to type you apple mac's ip followed by :8888

So if you developed a website on your mamp server and want to test it on a windows computer then you jusy need to type your_ip:8888/your_site.php and it would work perfectly

If find this helpful your testing my sites in ie

ps - sorry for not knowing the correct terminology, however I dont think the terminology was the problem but (maybe) it was a question where the answer is not known (as I found it really difficult finding it on google)